# Broken fraction module? Surely not -- Python

Tags: python, module

I'm working on improving my math and programming skills, and my programming skills are sort of in between baby and toddler stage.  I've been trying to get the gcd function from the Python fractions module to work for me, and it will work on small integers but not on large ones.  for example, if I run

```
from fractions import gcd
print gcd(37512, 84293)
```

And if I run

```
import fractions
a = 37512
b = 84293
cd = fractions.gcd(a, b)
print cd
```

I get the same thing in the output: a 1.  Just the integer "one".  Extensive manual testing has shown that this should *not* be the greatest common denominator.  What's going wrong here?

Comment: Could you show that "extensive manual testing", or whatever else convinced you the gcd isn't 1? What's the gcd according to you? Wolfram Alpha confirms it, and as you say the fraction module is almost certainly not this broken.

Comment: Found my problem -- I had done manual testing with integers in Python, like 

    37512 / 163,
which of course outputs 230 as an integer even though the "real" answer is 230.134969325 when I use

    37512 / 163.0.
Very amateur question.  Thanks for setting me straight.

Answer (score 2):

According to your Python code, my Python code, WebMath.com, and MathPortal.org the GCD of 37512 and 84293 is in fact 1. This link: http://www.mathportal.org/calculators/numbers-calculators/gcd-lcm-calculator.php gives a good explanation of why the GCD is what it is after inputting the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

As @Chandrew said the answer is 1. You can check it with any reasonable math software (here Sage based on Python):

```
sage: xgcd(37512,84293)
(1, 5220, -2323)
sage:  5220 * 37512 - 2323 * 84293
1
```